# can't splice number from array

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsx

I make tic tac toe where user can play against computer and I have such problem, when I try to remove checked boxes, the first time everything fine, but the second time can't remove numbers from array, so my description can make you confused and I write here what I get in console

```
  const [emptyDraws, setEmptyDraws] = useState<number | any>([
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
  ]);
```

When I click the third box, the an index 2 of the box in the array should be deleted

after my click, it automatically computer processes the random index of the empty box from "emptyDraws", for example number 5

All this means is that we have to delete two index of the box in the "emptyDraws", that is [5, 2]

```
  //finally we get array without [5, 2]
   const [emptyDraws, setEmptyDraws] = useState<number | any>([
    0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8,  // the array is a without numbers [2, 5]
  ]);
```

this helps me to know where can computer set the "O" sign, because every used number will removed as I did above.

finally, I can say what problem I have: the first time this function (what I wrote above) works, but the second time when the computer processes the number, it won't remove it from 'emptyDraws', and
next time the computer has an index of the box that is already filled

why sometimes can't remove numbers from array?,

you can see below the part of the code which is a become problem for me

```
 const [drawers, setDrawers] = useState<any | 0>(Array(9).fill(""));
   const [player, setPlayer] = useState<String | any>("x");

   // ========== Computer Move permission ========== \\
   const [computerMove, setComputerMove] = useState<boolean | null> (false);

   // ========== when I Click on box should do this ========== \\
   const handleClick = async (indexOfDraw: number) => {
    if (checkWin() || drawers[indexOfDraw] !== "") return;

     await spliceNumber(indexOfDraw);
     asMark(indexOfDraw);
     setComputerMove(!computerMove);
  };

  // ========== ComputerMove ========== \\
  const [emptyDraws, setEmptyDraws] = useState<number | any>([
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
  ]);

  // ========== Splice number after mark ========== \\
  const spliceNumber = async (index: number) => {
    const indexer = await emptyDraws.indexOf(index);

    if (indexer > -1) {
      await emptyDraws.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };

  // computer move steps
  useEffect(() => {
    if (computerMove === false) return;
    let computerIndex;

    for (let i = 0; i < emptyDraws.length; i++) {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * emptyDraws[i]);

      console.log("ranadom: " + random);

      computerIndex = emptyDraws[random];
    }

    handleClick(computerIndex);
  });
```

Comment: not going to make a difference, but indexOf and splice is not async so that await should not be there.

Comment: This line - `await emptyDraws.splice(index, 1);`. Never directly mutate state in React. Use the state setter returned as part of your `useState` hook.

Comment: @damonholden first thanks for your answer, but it not works, When the computer processes a random number, which should be deleted in the array, it gives me in the console but in the array, nothing happened

Comment: not saying it solves your issue but direct state mutation is objectively wrong in React. If you are still having issues post a sandbox reproduction and I'll debug.